# Ubuntu 13.10 isn't remembering my passwords anymore, why?

Tags: 13.10, password

Ubuntu's password management used to be working just fine for me, but around two weeks ago after running `apt-get upgrade`, I've noticed that now it keeps "forgetting" my passwords.

For instance, I need to manually enter passwords to unlock my ssh keys to use git, which previously was done automatically on login. My workplace's 802.11x authentication also no longer works, I need to manually re-auth just to connect to internet. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I installed seahorse but ultimately resolved the problem by setting my login password in the system settings to abc123, and then back to my real password. That seemed to sync the login keychain password as well, I think that using the standard unix `passwd` command didn't do that.

Comment: Hmmm. The keychain and login passwords lost synchronization. Either method would have worked. You are right. `passwd` does not do synchronization. Glad to hear that you fixed it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though the keyring is failing.

Steps to fix:

1. Click the Ubuntu icon in your Dash.
2. Type `seahorse`
3. Check if your passwords are there.
4. Click View and By Keyring
5. Right Click on Login and Change Password. Enter your old login (even if you didn't change it) and change it to your CURRENT password. The problem should be resolved.

If you still experience the problem, there is something wrong with the password storage system.

Try installing from a CLEAN Ubuntu. Upgrading doesn't always work...

Comment: I don't see the login password there, only my SSH password and PGP one. Also, seahorse isn't installed in Ubuntu 13.10 by default, I had to apt-get it.

Comment: Seahorse is installed by default. I think that is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, but ultimately the solution to this problem was much easier (see my answer below). Is it possible that using the `passwd` command didn't set the login password correctly?